# Serving a QGIS Project to Leaflet / MediaWiki Maps Extension

Tags: qgis, leaflet, qgis-3

I'm currently serving a custom map with qgis-mapserver and that works well. However, my next step is Mediawiki integration, and for reasons of GeoJSON overlays, I must use the Leaflet option there.

It appears to me that Leaflet only accepts TMS with x/y/z coordinates, not WMS with bbox parameters. If I am mistaken, please tell me how to make Leaflet use WMS.

If not, I have set up tilecache.cgi but that also works with a bbox parameter, though it creates the x/y/z tile structure on disk. I could also throw gdal2tiles at it.

Does anyone have the workflow from QGIS to MediaWiki Maps (with Leaflet) set up successfully? I've found nothing in Google nor the Maps or Leaflet documentations.

QGIS 3.8, MediaWiki 1.33.0 with Maps 7.3.0

The intended effect is similar to this: https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Maps/Geojson -- just with my own map source.

Comment: Leaflet `L.tileLayer.WMS` object is based on bbox strategy, but only supports tiled sources. If you have different source format (GeoJSON, ...), you could try `leaflet.wms` plugin: https://github.com/heigeo/leaflet.wms

Comment: thanks, that is one piece of the puzzle.

Comment: A WMS or tile service won't give you GeoJSON.

Comment: @nmtoken no, but Mediawiki Maps supports GeoJSON pages for geolocation of features, and it works only with leaflet.

Comment: I can't see the point of asking how to get WMS to work with Leaflet if, you want a GeoJSON input to Leaflet.  You''l need something that serves vector output like WFS using something like https://github.com/azgs/azgs-leaflet

Comment: Mediawiki Maps has a feature to show a map (from a WMS source, via Leaflet) and add a GeoJSON overlay to highlight a feature on the map. It's described here: https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Maps/Geojson